# How to Unpivot Columns dynamically in foreach loop in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using foreach loop to dynamically load file in database but in my source file year and month wise data is stored.If 2020 will come then issue will generate.I want to know that if i want to do unpivot of all those columns suppose 2020 and 2021 data came then it should store sales values in different column and month and year in different column.

By foreach loop i can read all file but if i want to unpivot it dynamically and want to store it in database.

if anyone have any idea how to resolve it or which process should follow then please let me know...

I am using Foreach Loop in ssis to loop through all files inside the folder.But when i want to unpivot files at that time it is giving error because yearwise column will change.
And in my folder am having different yearwise files.How can i unpivot it dynamically??

[image]

[image]

This is My source files i want to unpivot all this files dynamically in ssis
[image]

Comment: can you share your tried code..and post table structure with input and expected output in text format...

Comment: There is very little information available in your question. Please add some sample data, along with any query/transformations you have tried

Comment: SSIS really doesn't like to do things "dynamically". Your best best is going to be to get your raw data into SQL Server, and then run a stored proc to do the unpivot and transform your data dynamically. If at all possible, see if you can get your source file in an unpivoted format.

Comment: @DarkRob I have edited post.If you guys can help then please let me know..

Comment: @digital.aaron please have a look i have edited post.I will get files yearly or monthly based on that i want to make it dynamic.After getting raw data in sql server i need to merge all monthly or yearly tables.Do you have any idea how to merge all files means yearly or monthly columns will increase after that i can apply dynamically unpivot in sql server.

Comment: @pinkyadhikari: you mention `when i want to unpivot files at that time it is giving error`....please share this piece of code which is giving error, we'll help you to rectify that error